# How to create glowing light bulbs in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, light, lighting, glass

I would like to model hanging spherical bulbs like these in Eevee:
[image]

I thought I could follow this tutorial to make transparent spheres, then put a point light inside and it might come out reasonably:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtfNtpJa3hU

However when I try to make some spheres I get this:

[image]

And then when I sent them to Transmission =1, they turn into these flat grey things:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible to do in Eevee?

I know I can just set "emissions" to white, but this just washes out the color and shading. As you can see in the pictures of the actual hanging globe lights, they are not simply just white spheres but rather develop shading around the edges which simply making a high emission sphere does not capture at least not in Eevee.

I figure I must put a point light inside of a translucent sphere and it should then glow appropriately but can't make it work.

Any thoughts?

Here is my simple project with the 5 spheres:

https://easyupload.io/cjduoo

Thanks.

Comment: did you turn on all needed settings for glass materials in Eevee? Refraction in render settings and screen space refraction in material settings?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just checked your project and you have IOR set to 0, set it to 1.3 or 1.4

Comment: Thanks MikoCG. That helped. They now look like glass balls. Do you have any ideas on how to make them glow appropriately in Eevee? I tried putting a point lamp inside one and it didn't really do much except refect off the surface off the neighbors. Thanks again.

Comment: well, there can be multiple ways to do it. Personally I would do it with one single sphere, use noise or other texture with colorRamp in transmission and roughness to give it that look in picture and then use colorRamp again for emission strenght to make some parts emit more light and some emit less light

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this gonna work but yeah maybe -

1. In the **Material properties** activate Use Nodes and open the **shading**. Add a **Transparent BSDF shader** and a Mix node. Link the Principled Shader (already there) and the **Transparent BSDF** (shift+A) to the input side of the Mix node, and the output of the Mix node to the Surface input of the Output node.

2.Adjust the Fac setting of the Mix node to determine the amount of transparency.

*You can see transparency in Cycles, but not in **Eevee** until and unless the settings of the material, switch Blend Mode to opaque or one of the other options (just try usin' all on by one) and make sure this must be turned on
[image: SCREEN SPACE REFLECTIONS]

Comment: It was actually much easier, it was only IOR set to 0